# Quarto: .content-visible div dependent on params?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

Using quarto, I'd like to do something like:

```
---
params:
show_private_info: true
---

::: {.content-visible <ARGUMENT TESTING FOR `params$show_private_info`>}
Some private information
:::
```

Is that feasible?

Clearly something can be whipped up using an `asis` (`r`) code block `cat`ing out the markdown, with `eval` dependent on `params$show_private_info`, but I'd like to avoid that detour if possible ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3116#discussioncomment-4030946) as follows:

```
`r if (params$show_private_info) "::: {.content-hidden}"`

Some private information

`r if (params$show_private_info) ":::"`
```

with the additional recommendation to explicitly solve this by use of actual `profile`s instead.